# Script src using a passed variable from another page, document.createElement not working

Tags: parameters, src

I need your help for an issue that (maybe) is very easy to solve.
Doing a search on internet I've found something but I haven't understood how to make it working...

The problem is this:
I have an html page that passes a variable (the part number of a product) to another html page using the href link with parameters, in this way:

```
<a href="page2.html?partnumber=123456">TEST LINK</a>
```

In the second page I receive the partnumber correctly, but I want to use it as an src link for calling an external script in this second page.

The code that receives the variable on the second page (in the body; putting it in the head, it doesn't work) is:

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) url = window.location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var partnumbersrc = getParameterByName('partnumber') + '.js';
document.write(partnumbersrc);
</script>
```

It correctly writes the passed variable and writes *123456.js* on the page.

After this code, I have this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="123456.js"></script>
```

that I want to transform in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=partnumbersrc></script>
```

where *partnumbersrc* is the variable that has been passed from page1 to page2 (+ the *.js* string).

I already tried the solution with the code:

```
<script>
var script   = document.createElement('script');
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = partnumbersrc;
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

but it doesn't work.
I found that the only row that doesn't work is the one with the path of the script. If I write script.InnerHTML = ...., it works.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript"; 
script.src   = partnumbersrc;  
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried what you suggested, but unfortunately it does nothing. If I disable the string "document.write..." nothing appears in the page